# Why doesn't Vim search under cursor work in LaTeX file?

Tags: search, vim, latex

The word currently under the cursor can be searched by pressing `*` in Vim.

I find that if I have a `word_with_underscores` in a C++ file, then `*` searches for the entire word. But the same `word_with_underscores` in a LaTeX file only searches for a part of the word delimited by underscores. For example, if the cursor is on `u`, then only `underscores` is searched.

Why this change in behavior? How can I get the behavior in C++ file in a LaTeX file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of the `*` command, as well as `w` or `b`, depends on the option `iskeyword`. See

```
:h *
:h 'iskeyword'
```

The syntax file for the latex file type changes this option, removing the `_` character for the list.

On vim 7.4, `:set iskeyword?` returns the following with a C++ file:

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
```

but with a latex file:

```
iskeyword=48-57,a-z,A-Z,192-255
```

This is often changed by vim syntax files, to fit with the specificities of certain languages. For example, with a lisp file, the `-` is added. I don't know latex, but the `_` char has certainly a particular meaning in the syntax, in a way or another.

You can do the following in your `vimrc` to override this:

```
au FileType tex set iskeyword=48-57,_,a-z,A-Z,192-255
```

Comment: Thanks! I added this to my vimrc: let g:tex_isk="48-57,-,_,a-z,A-Z,192-255"